# MVC 2.0 Test Https locally

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

How i may test ssl with mvc locally using IIS 7.5.
Because by default when if i set RequireHttpsAttribte to controller in response i am getting : The requested resource can only be accessed via SSL.

Answer (score 0):

There's [an article here](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/387/using-visual-studio-2008-with-iis-7/) describing how to use Visual Studio 2008 with IIS 7 that may help.

Alternatively [Hosting WCF 4.0 Service on IIS 7.5 with SSL](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=487) may be of some assistance.

I'm not sure if yo have actually got an ssl cert from your question.